# Will NSXPCService work between user account processes without admin privilege in swift language?

Tags: swift, objective-c, macos

I need to use NSXPCService to communicate between 2 applications which is in user account it has no admin privilege, so can i use NSXPCService for this case?

I tried this service between daemon application and user application. so its worked but another case which i mentioned above is not working

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: okay, i removed that tag